# Parallel computing for cross-validation with big.matrix in R

Tags: r, bigdata, r-bigmemory, rparallel

I am trying to use `mclapply` to parallelize cross-validation for modeling fitting procedure for very large design matrix `X` (~10GB) and response vector `y`. Let's say `X` is of dimension `n-by-p`: `n=1000, p=1,000,000`. Since `X` is very huge, it's backed as `big.matrix` object, stored in disk, and accessed using methods in R package `bigmemory`.

The workflow for a 4-fold cross validation is as follows.

1. Set up indices vector `cv.ind` with length `n`, which stores a sequence of numbers from 1 to 4, indicating which observation in `X` belongs to which fold for CV.
2. Set up 4 cores. In the i-th core, copy corresponding training and test sub matrices for the i-th fold CV.
3. Fit a model for each fold in each core.
4. Collect results, return.

The cross-validation function looks like following.

```
cv.ncvreg <- function(X, y, ncore, nfolds=5, seed, cv.dir = getwd(), 
                      cv.ind) {
  ## some more setup ...
  ## ...
  ## ...
  ## pass the descriptor info to each core ##
  xdesc <- describe(X)
  ## use mclapply instead of parLapply
  fold.results <- parallel::mclapply(X = 1:nfolds, FUN = cvf, XX=xdesc, y=y, 
                                     cv.dir = cv.dir, cv.ind=cv.ind, 
                                     cv.args=cv.args,
                                     mc.set.seed = seed, mc.silent = F, 
                                     mc.cores = ncore, mc.preschedule = F)

  ## return results
}
```

The R function `cvf` is run in each core. It copies training/test matrices for i-th fold as two `big.matrix` objects, fits a model, computes some statistics, and returns results.

```
cvf <- function(i, XX, y, cv.dir, cv.ind, cv.args) {
  ## argument 'XX' is the descriptor for big.matrix
  # reference to the big.matrix by descriptor info
  XX <- attach.big.matrix(XX)

  cat("CV fold #", i, "\t--Copy training-- Start time: ", format(Sys.time()), "\n\n")
  ## physically copy sub big.matrix for training
  idx.train <- which(cv.ind != i) ## get row idx for i-th fold training
  deepcopy(XX, rows = idx.train, type = 'double',
           backingfile = paste0('x.cv.train_', i, '.bin'),
           descriptorfile = paste0('x.cv.train_', i, '.desc'),
           backingpath = cv.dir)
  cv.args$X <- attach.big.matrix(paste0(cv.dir, 'x.cv.train_', i, '.desc'))
  cat("CV fold #", i, "\t--Copy training-- End time: ", format(Sys.time()), "\n\n")

  cat("CV fold #", i, "\t--Copy test-- Start time: ", format(Sys.time()), "\n\n")
  ## physically copy remaining part of big.matrix for testing
  idx.test <- which(cv.ind == i) ## get row idx for i-th fold testing
  deepcopy(XX, rows = idx.test, type = 'double',
           backingfile = paste0('x.cv.test_', i, '.bin'),
           descriptorfile = paste0('x.cv.test_', i, '.desc'),
           backingpath = cv.dir)
  X2 <- attach.big.matrix(paste0(cv.dir, 'x.cv.test_', i, '.desc'))
  cat("CV fold #", i, "\t--Copy test-- End time: ", format(Sys.time()), "\n\n")

  # cv.args$X <- XX[cv.ind!=i, , drop=FALSE]
  cv.args$y <- y[cv.ind!=i]
  cv.args$warn <- FALSE

  cat("CV fold #", i, "\t--Fit ncvreg-- Start time: ", format(Sys.time()), "\n\n")
  ## call 'ncvreg' function, fit penalized regression model
  fit.i <- ncvreg(X=cv.args$X, y=cv.args$y, family=cv.args$family, 
                  penalty = cv.args$penalty,lambda = cv.args$lambda, convex = cv.args$convex)

  # fit.i <- do.call("ncvreg", cv.args)
  cat("CV fold #", i, "\t--Fit ncvreg-- End time: ", format(Sys.time()), "\n\n")

  y2 <- y[cv.ind==i]
  yhat <- matrix(predict(fit.i, X2, type="response"), length(y2))

  loss <- loss.ncvreg(y2, yhat, fit.i$family)
  pe <- if (fit.i$family=="binomial") {(yhat < 0.5) == y2} else NULL
  list(loss=loss, pe=pe, nl=length(fit.i$lambda), yhat=yhat)
}
```

Up to this point, the code works very well when the design matrix `X` is not too large, say `n=1000, p=100,000` with size ~1GB. **However, if `p=1,000,000` hence the size of `X` becomes ~10GB, the model fitting procedure in each core runs like forever!!!!! (the following portion):**

```
#...
cat("CV fold #", i, "\t--Fit ncvreg-- Start time: ", format(Sys.time()), "\n\n")
## call 'ncvreg' function, fit penalized regression model
fit.i <- ncvreg(X=cv.args$X, y=cv.args$y, family=cv.args$family, 
                penalty = cv.args$penalty,lambda = cv.args$lambda, convex = cv.args$convex)
# fit.i <- do.call("ncvreg", cv.args)
cat("CV fold #", i, "\t--Fit ncvreg-- End time: ", format(Sys.time()), "\n\n")
#...
```

---

**Notes**:

1. If I run 'ncvreg()' on the raw matrix (10GB) once, it takes ~2.5 minutes.
2. **If I run the cross validation sequentially using `for` loop but not `mclapply`, the code works well, the model fitting for each fold 'ncvreg()' works fine too (~2 minutes), though the whole process takes ~25 minutes.**
3. I tried 'parLapply' at first with the same issue. I switched to 'mclapply' due to reason [here](http://file:///Users/yazeng/Desktop/v55i14.pdf).
4. **The data copy step (i.e., `deepcopy` portion) in each core works well, and takes ~2 mins to get the training and test data sets copied and file-backed on disk**.
5. I tried to monitor the CPU usage, below is one screenshot. As we can see, in the left figure, each of 4 rsessions takes ~25% CPU usage, while there is a process, **kernel_task** uses up ~100% CPU. As time elapses, **kernel_task** can take even 150% CPU. In addition, the CPU history panel (right bottom) shows that most of the CPU usage is from system, not user, since the red area dominates green area.

[image]

---

**My questions:**

1. Why does the model fitting process take forever when in parallel? What could be possible reasons?
2. Am I on the right track to parallelize the CV procedure for big.matrix? Any alternative ways?

I appreciate any insights for helping fix my issue here. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Ideally you would be using `sub.big.matrix` as I suggested before on previously permuted data but whatever you need to do. By running `deepcopy` you create a copy of that object in memory.  I suspect it slows down in parallel because you are copying all 4 at the same time and R isn't able to handle the memory efficiently.  Try benchmarking the different steps to find out which step it is hanging on and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @cdeterman. Actually, ``deepcopy`` does work! ``deepcopy`` does physical copy of the data, and allows file backing on disk. So I don't need to copy the object in the memory. Based on my experiment, the ``deepcopy`` procedure works well, and takes ~2mins. It's the model fitting step in each fold that runs like forever!!

Comment: If you look at the ``deepcopy`` code portion, what I did is to copy the data and have it file-backed in disk by providing the directory and the backing-file names.

Comment: In terms of ``sub.big.matrix``, I've compared it with ``deepcopy``. I found that using ``deepcopy`` is even faster than ``sub.big.matrix`` for creating a sub-matrix out of ``big.matrix`` object when the sub-matrix is also very large and cannot be fit into memory. Not to mention that ``sub.big.matrix`` requires the sub-matrix is contiguous.

Comment: Do you have another implementation of `ncvreg`?  Regardless of the CV method, the function from the `ncvreg` package does not accept `big.matrix` objects.  You code as it stands is not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that, @cdeterman. Yes. I have extended ``ncvreg`` function such that it can accept ``big.marix`` objects.

Comment: You should provide that as well.  Given that you say that is the part that takes longer you should provide it.

Comment: Or at least just show the part you altered given that the function is rather verbose.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, the function ``ncvreg`` is a little messy since it calls some C-level functions to do the tedious computation. Basically what I did was to write some counterpart functions in C++ level which utilize ``bigmemory`` API to handle computation for ``big.matrix``.

Comment: So wherever there is a C function called by ``ncvreg``, you can just imagine there is a C++ counterpart that can handle ``big.matrix`` object. Despite of this, all the R level code are pretty much the same.

Comment: @cdeterman, I am not sure whether that's helpful for you. But if you need to to through the code, I will push it to GitHub soon, though I need to clean it up a little bit. Thanks for your interests in my question.